# Skip date in MySQL query if it is empty when using < and >

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query to skip the date if it is not selected in the form. So far I got this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id, dateTime FROM Message WHERE IFNULL(dateTime, '') < '' AND IFNULL(dateTime, '') > '' AND IFNULL(body, '') LIKE '%%';
```

If I run for e.g.: `IFNULL(body, '') LIKE '%%';` using `LIKE` it is working fine it returns the expected results. But if I use `<` or `>` and if the date is empty it does not return me any results.

My question is how can I skip searching for a date if it is empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id, dateTime
FROM Message
where dateTime IS NULL or dateTime <> '';
```

Comment: @JimBolster: You are welcome. Please note: While looking quite horrible, your condition should also have worked if you would have gotten the boolean operators right: You would have needed to use `OR` instead of `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do ::

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id, dateTime
FROM Message
where IFNULL(dateTime,'nullValue') <> '';
```

Comment: That's not equivalent. This will *not* return rows without a date.

Comment: If dateTime is null, the `IFNULL` command will change it to `''` which is equal to `''`, making the condition (`'' <> ''`) false.

Comment: But I have not checked for equality, it is `<>`, The row will be skipped in the resultset

Comment: Exactly, it will be skipped. That's *not* what the OP wants. He wants to skip the *check* for rows without a date, in other words: He wants to have the rows where `dateTime` IS NULL.

Comment: Ohhk :-)
Sorry mate, Thanks a lot mate, 
Thumbs up(+1) for your answer and your effort in making me understand...:-)